# Web application shutdown multiple times a day

Tags: asp.net

I have a `framework 3.5` website which is shutting down multiple times a day. The reason is

> **Event message**: Application is shutting down.
>   **Reason**: A subdirectory in the Bin application directory was changed or
>   renamed.

- The code is not writing to the bin.
- Anti-virus is not the issue.
- `web.config` is not being changed.
- Any subfolders are not being deleted.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Checkout the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941260/does-changing-any-sub-directory-or-file-in-an-asp-net-application-recycles-the-a

Comment: I looked at that post too, I have sub-directories that the users can upload files to, but the timings of the shutdowns do not correspond to those uploads.

Comment: How did you verify that?

Comment: I am watching the directories constantly. Also from the logs. Sometimes there is just 1 user (It has been me sometimes) and it happens then, and I did not upload anything at that point. Could the code be doing something which updates the dlls? There is nothing that is done explicitly to update the dlls.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Eventlog message something is being changed in the Bin directory. But, there are few more things you could check.

Your application pool may get recycled if

1. You've set a max memory limit
2. If you've set it to recycle in regular intervals

To check this right click on the ApplicationPool being used by your web application and select the "Recycling..." option. You'll see a dialog similar to the following.

[image]

Comment: MemoryLimit is default (0) which means no limit.
Also, the regular interval is 29 days. It happens every day sometimes 20 times each day.

Comment: Did you note that regular time interval is in minutes? What's the value in yours?

Comment: it is 1740, approx 29 days.

Comment: Ok then we can rule that out. Open up Windows Performance monitor and see how the worker process perform with your server's memory utilisation.

Comment: And, did you investigate whether there's any change to bin directory?

Comment: There is no change to the bin directory when these shutdowns occur.
I do not have access to the performance monitor as this does not happen in my localhost, but only happens on the testing and production server.